# Do I need to pay taxes on my mother in law giving us "rent" money?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, rent

This is for California, USA

My MIL is living with us these days and we do not actually charge her for any rent. She has a small business that has sporadically yields some income. She insists on paying us with that money as my wife is paying for the mortgage on a house (separate from the one we all live in, which is owned by me) they (wife and MIL) own jointly. The amount would be between 10k to 15k a year.

How does this work in terms of taxes? Do we need to report the money MIL gave us as "rent" money?

Comment: Just to be clear, the house you all live in is a different house than the one that your wife and MIL own jointly?

Comment: yes that is correct, the house we live in is under my name only

Comment: Isn't your MIL just paying part of the mortgage on the house that she and your wife own jointly?

Comment: @quid I guess so, but she is transferring the money to my wife's account instead of paying the mortgage directly, as the income isn't consistent and she would be late on payments for most of the month if coming directly from her account.

Comment: To me, if anything, this is your wife short term lending your MIL her half of the mortgage payment and being reimbursed sporadically.

Comment: Are there 2 houses? The one you all live in and another your wife and mom own? Still not clear.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer yes sorry, we all live in house1 under my name, my wife and MIL jointly own house2, my wife doesn't want MIL to live alone so she came to live with us in house1.

Comment: Assuming that none of the parties are taking business deductions from this, who is to say that your MIL, a residing  *family member* , isn't just contributing to household expenses?  The ultimate answer is that you should consult your accountant to see if tax law where you live applies.

Comment: MIL is giving money to you to cover house 2 that she partially owns. No issue there.

Comment: Even if she was just giving you money for no reason at all YOU wouldn't owe taxes. She might.

Comment: @JohnFx well we don't want her to owe taxes if possible as well.

Comment: @tom I'd be surprised if her giving you money gave rise to a tax liability on her part.

Comment: Who's on the mortgage?

Answer (score 1):

Wait, are your MIL and Spouse both co-owners, and it's the primary residency for your MIL correct and not your residency? Is your wife handling the money for your MIL? How much mortgage does she (MIL) pay, and you (your spouse/you) pay in %.

If she pays 100% of her own mortgage, then provides you the 10k-15k; then it's clearly a gift, and it's subjected to tax.

I think the case is this >>>> Double Check against ***"Gifted Money"***, follow the link below to the IRS website, and see if it applies to your situation.

https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/frequently-asked-questions-on-gift-taxes#2